SQLAlchemy Pending Rollback with FastAPI
Having quite a bit of issues with SQLAlchemy and Postgres where nearly daily I get
raise exc.PendingRollbackError(\nsqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back.

I have tried many solutions online but none seem to fix the problem.
Below is a "database.py" file that I have:
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql://{os.environ.get('DB_USER')}:{os.environ.get('DB_PASS')}@{os.environ.get('DB_HOST')}/{os.environ.get('DB_NAME')}"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=3600, pool_size=20, max_overflow=10)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

On POST, I have the following try/except to handle exceptions and rollback, however, something slides through.
    from database.database import SessionLocal
    self.db = SessionLocal() 

    new_session = Sessions(
        id=session_id,
        user_id=session.user_id,
        email=session.email,
    )

    try:
        self.db.add(new_session)
        self.db.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        self.db.rollback()
        self.logger.error(f"Failed to create session")
        self.logger.error(e)

During testing, I can't recreate the error. I come back the next day and the site is unusable again. I cannot figure out why this is happening.
I do have a health check API (hit every 30 seconds) that was intended handle another issue where the FastAPI connection loses connectivity to the Database (think database restarts, etc). All it does is a lookup to try to revive the connection.

Are you ensuring that your sessions are closed after each request, as discussed here?
